# Transaction confirmed for hours, not available in balance

Tags: transactions, confirmations

My bitcoin transaction has been confirmed for more than 24 hours and also on the block chain but it has not yet reflected on the receivers balance, all transaction details are correct,what could be the problem

Comment: It is not a new wallet,the blockchain shows that this transaction has been received and spent but still nothing in the balance, could the receiver have two wallet for same wallet I'd? Here is the wallet I'd
35yXZcnDEXWHA6HBhjMpcB48RqnwzfpdGp Here is the transaction hash
3ea559060a90f085ba96c507b66f0e55ed84d0c9853146f07294ba83e3f3dab8

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you double checked that you sent the coins to the right BTC adddress: 
The wallet of the receiver should be connected to a full Bitcoin-node, either his own node or another node. This node could be down or not updated to current block height.
So you might ask the receiver if (s)he used the same wallet already successfully for other transactions before and if the connected node is online and synchronized to the latest blocks already.
Another reason could be that the receiver looks up the balance in the wrong wallet. So you might ask if the receiver has more than one wallet and if it could be that he looked in the wrong one. The wallet probably allows to see associated addresses.

Comment: I actually sent a transaction to the same address a day before and it went through successfully..

Comment: Could this be be caused by a low fee? Because I noticed the first transaction had a higher fee than the stuck one,although the later is a bigger amount.

Comment: @Macdaniel if the tx is confirmed, then the fee was sufficient, and should no longer be a consideration for why the recipient's wallet isn't showing the correct balance. As @ tempo mentioned, the receiver's wallet is either not synced to the network, or is having some other internal error in displaying the balance.

Comment: Is there any way I can be able to resend this transaction, what could be done to make the fund available as soon as possible please

Comment: if the transaction has already confirmations in the blockchain you'd spend again if you resend. The one you sent yesterday cannot be cancelled. So if you"re sure the transaction has many confirmations in the blockchain (check in at least two explorers) then the receiver needs to make sure he has a working and trusted wallet.

Comment: Please direct me on how to resend.

Comment: What can I do if this is a multisig address I sent to

Comment: No difference for you if you send to a multisig address. The difference is on receivers side as soon as they want to spend the received coins again (not your business). Then they need the required number of signatures. If you can show the number of confirmations of the transaction then the rest needs to be sorted out by the receiver.

Comment: copy this address
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/XXX
and replace the XXX by the receivers address 3abc....
Then you see all the transactions of the 3abc... address. Find your transaction and click on the top of the section on the hash. Then you'll see details about your transaction, scroll down until you find something like "Confirmations  145". If your transaction is showing up and the number of confirmations is at least 6 then the receiver should accept the fact that the funds are now under his control and that you can do nothing anymore.

Comment: Hi guys ,this wallet has been synchronized and now the funds show as spent but still not available in balance,is there any possibility?

Comment: What does it mean, the wallet shows the transfer of X BTC but the balance before and after stays flat? Is it a common wallet or a new one? If synchronized it sounds like a bug in the wallet app. Nevertheless the blockchain explorers will show you the truth and if the receiver has the seed/ private keys another wallet could be the solution.